# GLSL Uniform layout binding and textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

I'm a bit confused on what would be the right way to bind the texture when uniforms are using the layout binding.

```
layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform uCommon
{
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
};

layout(binding = 1, std140) uniform uModel
{
    mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
};

layout(binding = 3) uniform sampler2D uTexture;
```

To bind my first texture I should use "GL_TEXTURE0 + 3"?

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
```

Is this the correct way?

**EDIT:** Or is sampler using a separate binding from other uniforms? Can I use:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D uTexture;
```

while still using

```
layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform uCommon
```

Comment: Does it work or not? If it doesn't work, then show an complete example of what is not working. If it works, then please explain why you ask the question and what kind of explanation you expect. Atm, "Yes" would be a valid answer.

Comment: Why do you think that uniform block binding indices have anything to do with sampler binding locations?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't think op is taking about the uniform block binding index. I guess they mean the layout binding for the uniform sampler (which corresponds to the texture unit).

Comment: [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification; 4.4.6 Opaque-Uniform Layout Qualifiers; page 79](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf): Image and sampler types both take the uniform layout qualifier identifier for binding .... **The identifier binding specifies which unit will be bound.**

Comment: BDL, it works. But it even works when "uTexture" is bound to "0" (while "uCommon" is bound to "0" too) and "GL_TEXTURE0 + 0" is used. So I'm not sure if sampler is using a separate binding or not. P.s. I'm not getting any GL warnings or errors.

Comment: @Gediminas See the comment of Nicol Bolas. Uniform block binding indices have nothing to do with sampler binding locations. These are different things. They don't have to be unique across all types of "binding".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uniform block binding indices have nothing to do with sampler binding locations. These are different things.

The *integer-constant-expression*, which is used to specify the binding point or unit has not to be unique across all usages of the keyword **`binding`**.

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification; 4.4.5 Uniform and Shader Storage Block Layout Qualifiers; page 77](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> The binding identifier specifies **the uniform buffer binding point corresponding to the uniform or shader storage block, which will be used to obtain the values of the member variables of the block**.

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification; 4.4.6 Opaque-Uniform Layout Qualifiers; page 79](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> Image and sampler types both take the uniform layout qualifier identifier for binding:
>
> ```
> layout-qualifier-id :
>     binding = integer-constant-expression
> ```
>
> **The identifier binding specifies which unit will be bound**.